# How to display Microsoft Outlook message files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone know how to programatically display an email saved from Microsoft Outlook as a file via iOS? The original file is saved as either .eml or .msg format and stored in a filestore. I then download this file and need to display the contents (with links to attachments) in an iOS device.

I have looked at using UIWebView and QLPreviewController but cant see a suitable file format to use for saved email files.

If direct viewing of .msg or .eml files is not possible, is there a standard format that I could convert to so that i can display the saved emails (as files) in iOS?

Comment: What exactly is Outlook that you are talking about?  Is it an app made by EC Media Pvt?  Or is it OMP, Outlook Webmail for iOS that you are talking about?  Or is it a Mac OS application that you are talking about?  Perhaps, you should make the very subject clear when you ask a question.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. The email is from Microsoft Outlook and saved as a file in the cloud as a .msg or a .eml. I want to download this file (similar to downloading a .pdf or .doc file) and display it on an iOS device. 

I dont mind if I have to convert the original file to a different file format if necessary.